# Как задать разные фоны с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, css3

На макете видно эллипс слева и прямоугольник справа. Так вот вопрос: как задать два бэкграунда через CSS, чтобы всё хорошо работало?[image: фото]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient()

Comment: @AndreyFedorov: ну, дали Вы ссылку. Ну, ушёл человек по ней, забыв про этот вопрос. Кому Вы лучше делаете? Зачем гадите сообществу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 70px 50%, #E9CDDA 119px, transparent 120px), 
    linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF 50%, #E9CDDA 50%);
  
  
  height: 100%;
}
```